# Git: Use different branches for each site

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 2 sites, using a same CMS, but needed to be customize. Is it possible to have one site use master branch, and another site to use another branch? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is probably 'yes', but it is impossible to tell you 'how' unless you provide more information. At a minimum you need to say what CMS you are using and where you are hosting your git repository.

Comment: Sorry i might be unclear. We have our own cms, and all sites are pointing to it. We do not want to duplicate the entire core just for this new site that needs to be customized. So we are wondering if it is at all possible to have the other sites use the main branch and this new site to use another branch, without actually making a copy of the codebase. I think there isn't but i just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand good your question, maybe you can have your CMS on **master branch**, and two more branches **site one branch** and **site two branches**. So every time you update your CMS, you will merge **master branch** to both site branches, and on this site branches you can make customization.

Answer (score -1):

Although it is possible, it is highly impractical to do so as it will get really messy, and a merge or stash or any other command can mess around with the branches.

You will have to tread very carefully if you do it.

Comment: There is no intention to actually merge after customizing the main branch on a new branch. we just wanted to save space and not actually copy the entire codebase just for the other site.